# Best trigonometry book for complete beginner

Tags: reference-request

What are some best trigonometry books for complete beginner I can't decide between S.L loney and I.M Gelfand which would be better for understanding concepts from scratch

Comment: I have read Gelfan'd and it's a wonderful little book. Haven't heard of the other.

Comment: Loney's book for a complete beginner???

Answer (score 0):

I'll activate my way-back machine and recommend "Mathematics for the Million" by Lancelot Hogben available for a quite reasonable price at Amazon.

Do not expect extreme rigor.

Answer (score 0):

I've read about one-fifth of the book "TRIGONOMETRY $3$rd edition by Cynthia Young" and it is exactly what you are looking for.
This book is written in a very easy to understand manner,and the best thing is it contains a lot of questions for increasing your grasp on those concepts.

Comment: Your enthusiasm is appreciated, but perhaps you could manage without yelling?

Answer (score 0):

For an absolute beginner, you might look at:

"Get your head around: Basic Trigonometry I" by Austin Hartnell-Jones.

[https://www.amazon.com/Get-Your-Head-Around-Trigonometry-ebook/dp/B08VH48VJB/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08VH48VJB)

It uses very understandable language and starts out assuming you don't even know what an angle is. Covers the main functions (sin, cos, tan and their inverses). Includes Pythagoras' theorem (and proof) and goes a little into graphs of the functions.

Answer (score -1):

**Prashant Sharma's '*Trigonometry for JEE, ISI, KVPY, CMI & PRMO'***
proves to be the best for the beginners. He writes in detail and covers every possible route to unfolding the concept.The language used is simple to understand. It often happens that the beginners don't have the prerequisite knowledge for understanding trigonometry. He has even added that in his book. Plus there are topic wise problems with difficulty levels ranging from easy to advanced.

PS: I hardly used any additional material for trigonometry during my JEE prep. This book was more than sufficient. The best part is the precise hints and beautiful solutions to each problem in the last of every chapter.The book is available on Amazon. A must try!

[Trigonometry for JEE, ISI, KVPY, CMI & PRMO by Prashant Sharma](https://www.amazon.in/dp/9354730558/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_i_XVH2YVYTWBETSX0HTNGS)